# How to create Multi-node private ethereum blockchain network (windows platform)

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I need help in how we can create multi-node private network on ethereum blockchain preferably on windows platform. 
My Approach (please suggest if I can follow some better one):
First I want to try to create multi-node network on same machine using different geth instances. Then I want to move forward with different machines are separate nodes as part of that network.

Please suggest me how to achieve above.

Answer (score 2):

firstly, all node `must share the same genesis block.`

assume there are `node A` and `node B`

when testing nodes in the same IP address, they must have the different port number

`node A` geth option example:

```
--ipcdisable --port 30303 -- rpc --rpcport 8545
```

`node B` geth option example:

```
--ipcdisable --port 30304 -- rpc --rpcport 8546
```

The following is the process of making a connection between node A and node B.

`node A` javascript console:

```
admin.nodeInfo.enode
```

output is like:

> "enode://5bb8cc6ca2520ce27ea8b3940a5d04bd5893039d1737bf14913240a8bcbcf07fadabd87271f1a03f5647c7475f63b66177dc9544c8efe1079098a4eedfb42b16@[::]:30300?discport=0"

`Node B` javascript console:

```
admin.addPeer("enode://5bb8cc6ca2520ce27ea8b3940a5d04bd5893039d1737bf14913240a8bcbcf07fadabd87271f1a03f5647c7475f63b66177dc9544c8efe1079098a4eedfb42b16@[::]:30300?discport=0")
```

Comment: Thanks @TLHBM. admin.addPeer() returns me 'true' but when I run admin.peers() to see the added peers it returns null.
I am creating two nodes on the same system and trying to establish ethereum private network locally. Both the nodes have different directory where its data get stored. 
OS is Windows 10 and using windows powershell to run geth.

Comment: I added geth option example.